# Replace tab for newline and remove newlines together with SED

Tags: bash, sed

I have tabs (five) between these words:

`cat                    dog`

and I want this output:

```
cat
dog
```

I tried this: `sed 's/\t/\n/g; /^$/d' pets`
and the output was the same as with `sed 's/\t/\n/g' pets`:

```
cat




dog
```

I had to execute sed two times to get what I wanted. Like this `sed 's/\t/\n/g' pets>temp` after `sed '/^$/d' temp`

Is there a way to get the desired output with one command?

Comment: `sed 's/[\t][\t]*/\n/g'` ? You can eliminate the *character class* notation (e.g. the `[` and `]`, but they make it clear you are addressing characters. It's up to you. `sed 's/\t\t*/\n/g'` is equivalent.

Comment: `xargs -n1` might also suit, all non-space sequence of characters will get displayed on separate lines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Continuing from my comment. The problem with `sed 's/\t/\n/g` is you will replace **each** `'\t'` with a `'\n'`. You want to replace a *sequence* of tabs with a *single* newline. For that you need:

```
sed 's/\t\t*/\n/g'
```

or if you like explicitly enclosing the `'\t'` in `[ ]` that's fine as well.

The expression `'\t'` matches a single tab, when followed by `'\t\t*'` it matches a tab *and zero or more tabs that follow* replacing the *sequence* with a single `'\n'`, resulting in your desired output:

```
cat
dog
```

The `g` (globally) at the end will just replace each sequence with a single newline, e.g.

```
"cat     dog           fish"
```

(separated by tabs), becomes

```
cat
dog
fish
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of tabs is important, BRE will let you specify bounds by escaping the curly braces, like this:

```
$ sed $'s/\t\{5\}/\\\n/' <<<$'one\t\t\t\t\ttwo'
one
two
```

Note that you haven't specified an operating system so it's unknown whether you're using GNU sed, which would let you include things like `\t` in your regex. (I use FreeBSD and macOS, where sed does not have this capability.) But you HAVE mentioned that you're using `bash`, which supports ["format expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting). You can use this bash feature to insert "literal" special characters into your script.